# ApplePaySession is not defined no-undef error in React

Tags: reactjs, applepay, applepayjs

I am just trying to validate whether apple pay is supported on browser or not  with following code. But it gives error on safari (ipad) / macbook.

```
ApplePaySession' is not defined no-undef
```

Following code, I had written in ReactJs.

```
if (window.ApplePaySession) {
      if (ApplePaySession.canMakePayments) {
        alert('hi, I can do ApplePay.....')
      }
```

but gives undefined error!

If anyone can help? Why ApplePaySession is undefined? Do we need to import ApplePaySession? Or do we need to add any sdk?

Comment: finally it worked. By writing the following code.


`if (window.ApplePaySession) {
      if (window.ApplePaySession.canMakePayments) {
        alert('hi, I can do ApplePay.....')
  }`

Just make sure, you are running the app on secure environment i.e on HTTPS. 

Apple pay documention is worst.